# What is a good link to examples of enaml being used with traits and matplotlib?

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, traits, chaco, enaml

I have done GUI construction but not in Python. From other stack exchange questions and my own investigation. It looks like I want to use enaml and traits for the bulk of this work. Are there any links or references to help me get started.

This is a scientific application integrating matplotlib plots and text boxes and buttons (Very simple I think). I have gone through this example but don't understand it too well http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html

I have also gone through the Enthough Chaco examples and don't get very far. Has somebody built a program that I could run and look at their code? Or is their a repository of examples I am not aware of? I found the enaml examples but the example with matplotlib is basic and does not show me how to connect my algorithms to the plots. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but for additional context:

1) Use https://github.com/nucleic/enaml, along with https://github.com/enthought/traits-enaml

2) Example: 
https://github.com/nucleic/enaml/blob/master/examples/widgets/mpl_canvas.enaml

Comment: Thanks Jonathan traits-enaml seems to be what I need but I get the following error  API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1
when i execute `code`from enaml.qt.qt_application import QtApplication

Comment: actually I just got an example to work. I use spyder normally to code in and spyder and QT don't play well together on my Windows system. So I closed spyder and the program runs and a matplotlib plot comes up in a window.

Comment: Michael, likely the compatibility problem with spyder and Qt would be the same as it is on the Canopy GUI running in PyLab mode. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/64158730-Running-a-Qt-program-from-the-Canopy-GUI